# Using Gmail to manage multiple email accounts (not all @gmail.com)

Tags: gmail, account-management, webmail

Can you use Gmail like you'd use Outlook or Mac Mail, i.e., be able to see a bunch of accounts and use them from inside Gmail?

I know that you can do this in the new Outlook.com but we're already very familiar with Gmail.

The accounts I have vary (some @gmail, some @hotmail, and a couple of work ones) although I presume you'd add them by using IMAP and SMTP user names so you'd be able to add any account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I have several email accounts tied into my Gmail.

You want to have a look at the `Accounts and Import` tab under "Settings". There you can add other email addresses that you own.

Obviously, if it's not Gmail, you'll need to know some other information, like the POP3 and/or IMAP server information (password, port). You'll also need to confirm that you control the address before you can add it to Gmail.

More information at [Gmail support](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21289&topic=1669030&ctx=topic).